# Switch remote origin to mirrored repo w/o recloning

Tags: git

I have git repo in Stash which is mirrored to Gitlab.

How do I switch my local repo to use the mirrored Gitlab ?

So i dont have to re-clone the repo.

Answer (score 2):

The association between your local repository and another one somewhere else is called a "remote". Remotes can be configured at will with the `git remote` command; the [full documentation is here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote).

Most likely, you want to change the existing remote named "origin" (which was created by default when you cloned) to point at the URL of the Gitlab repo. That will look something like this:

```
git remote set-url origin git@gitlab.com/something/something
```